# How to keep Realm data in the same order as entered

Tags: swift, realm

I have an application where I need to keep the data in the same order as it is entered.  The data is entered into a List property.  Everything works great until I have to delete an item.  When the delete occurs the last item on the List takes the place of the one that was deleted.  The UITableView shows the correct number of items but is not synchronized with the realm List.

An example would be if I had data:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

I then delete:

3

The realm data looks like this:

1, 2, 6, 4, 5

The tableview looks like this:

1, 2, 4, 5, 6

The desired result of the realm data would match the tableview output.

Is there any way to keep the order of the data from changing after items are deleted?

Comment: Realm always returns items in the same order they are added. From your question it looks like it is doing it's job as the tableview is in the right order. Where and how are you seeing the "realm data"?

Comment: Realm doesn't return objects in the same order they were added. The order that objects are returned in is undefined, and, as the original question notes, can change when objects are removed.

Comment: Ravi, I see the changes using the realm browser.

Comment: Please share the code you're using to retrieve the objects in which you're seeing the objects in an unexpected order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in a Realm are inherently unordered. If you wish to retrieve objects in a specific order that you control, you can do so by inserting them into a `List` property of an object, or by sorting the `Results` that you use to retrieve them.

Comment: The objects are in a list property.  They stay in order until one of the objects is deleted.  That is when the order changes.

Comment: Deleting an object does not cause the order of the objects within the list to change. Are you expecting that the object being added to a list property would impact the order of objects retrieved via something other than that list property?

Comment: Thanks,  I finally learned how to sort the results!  I added a date property in the model, created a var of 'Results' which is sorted by date.  The data in the Realm Browser changed the order of the data after a delete, but the tableview displayed the correct data in the correct order.