# know which element of an Object changed in Realm Collection Change notification?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm, swift4

I added a notification for a collection of object. I observed it like the code below. inside the *switch case* block in the update section, I can only get the indices of the modified object. but, I want to know which variable of the modifiedObject has changed. is there a way to access that?

```
notificationTokens.conversationMessages = Result?.observe {[weak self] changes in
        self?.result = Array(Result!)
        if self?.isLoaded == false { return }
        switch changes {
        case let .update(_, deletions, _, modifications):
            if deletions.count > 0 {
                self?.updateUI(scrollToEnd: true)
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get the insertions, deletions and changes. But first there are a few things that you should be aware of:

The results set you're observing should be an ordered query, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43713282/how-to-keep-realm-data-in-the-same-order-as-entered) for more details. The criteria is up to you as developer.

Maybe an example would be

```
let mySortedObjects = realm.objects(MyObject.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "createdAt", ascending: true)
```

The `case let .update(_, deletions, _, modifications):` statement intializes the `deletions`, `insertions` and `modifications` variables, each one being an array of integers, so this syntax is short for `modifications: [Int]`. The integers contained into the `modifications` array are the indexes of the changed elements in the collection.

Back to the `case let .update(_, deletions, _, modifications)` statement, the first variable you're dismissing with `_` is the results set (the same as the original query, called `mySortedObjects: Results<MyObject>`), so your code can be changed to

```
case let .update(results, deletions, _, modifications):
```

With that in mind, the changed elements can be obtained more easily:

```
case let .update(results, deletions, _, modifications):
    for index in modifications {
        // modifiedObject is an instance of `MyObject`
        let modifiedObject = results[index]
    }
```

Comment: I think I misused the word element. I meant by element variables. for example if my modifiedObject has 2 variable : variable1:  Int and variable2: String. I want to know if the change was made on variable1 or variable2. is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you `observe` a `Results<MyObject>` set there is no possibility to know which variable changed. The Realm documentation states that "[Collection notifications] consist of the indices of objects that have been added, removed, or modified since the last notification."

If you want to know which property was changed for a single object you can refer to _Object notifications_: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#object-notifications